# Can we witness Optical illusion in which sun appears to set in mid sea than at horizon?

Tags: visible-light, refraction, geometric-optics, atmospheric-science, sun

I was searching for optical illusions and came across a video on youtube where sun seems to set in the mid of sea instead of setting at the horizon? Can anyone please explain how this illusion takes place.
The video can be searched by the name
" sun setting in the wrong place. Strange sunset December 25,2017.
Or link is
https://youtu.be/mJskaUw6yyo

Comment: See "atmospheric refraction" and mirages.

Comment: @josephh No. In this case it is just a matter of fog. Mirages would look totally different, in a clear sky.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of fog towards the horizon. So much fog that you just **cannot tell where the sky ends and where the sea begins**. In fact the only way to tell the exact position of the horizon is by the position of the setting sun !

Comment: You can see the position of the real horizon when they pan right in the video.

Comment: You are  right, but is goes fast and it is difficult to relate the real horizon farther from the sun. One does see the fog **over** the horizon there.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this paralax effect on the top floor of a hotel window. I saw the sunset over and over again in Texas. I realized the sun on the horizon, meant the sun was high in the sky over say Australia and the ocean. The sun shines on bothbof earth hemispheres at the same time. As well as leaves both hemispheres to night time. South America was experiencing the same thing I was experiencing in north America,  just  at a different angle.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/436132)